# jasper reports, group data in bar chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I need to create a report with total of activities in months. I am using  `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` to fill data in report like

[image: example1]

Also I need to add a **Bar Chart** like

[image: example2]

In my jasper file, I have

```
<categoryDataset>
    <dataset incrementType="Column"/>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Complete"]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Complete"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{complete}]]></valueExpression>
        <labelExpression><![CDATA["Complete"]]></labelExpression>
    </categorySeries>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["To do"]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["To do"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{todo}]]></valueExpression>
        <labelExpression><![CDATA["To do"]]></labelExpression>
    </categorySeries>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Errors"]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Errors"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{errors}]]></valueExpression>
        <labelExpression><![CDATA["Errors"]]></labelExpression>
    </categorySeries>
</categoryDataset>
```

But I get this error:

[image: error pic]

**Where I only get the last value of my query**

can I group by month data? like in the second picture?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `categoryExpression` property. Right now you have the same value as in `seriesExpression`. That's why a new category is created with only values for that series.

You should have something like the following:

```
<categorySeries>
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Complete"]]></seriesExpression>
    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["$F{MONTH}"]]></categoryExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{complete}]]></valueExpression>
</categorySeries>
<categorySeries>
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["To do"]]></seriesExpression>
    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["$F{MONTH}"]]></categoryExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{todo}]]></valueExpression>
</categorySeries>
<categorySeries>
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Errors"]]></seriesExpression>
    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["$F{MONTH}"]]></categoryExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{errors}]]></valueExpression>
```

Or whatever the `Month` field is named.